# How do I connect my registration form (admin) to my database TACLC with table named tbl_admin?

Tags: c#, database

The created account will be used as an admin to login. I haven't put anything yet and I don't have any idea. Still searching on how to connect to the database.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Connect me to the database first");
    }
```

Comment: what you did ? This is the form where you ask the error of logical thing.

Comment: what's your database? sqlserver, mysql, msccess?

Comment: I haven't don't anything yet. I need someones recommendation on how to connect my registration form to my database...

Comment: My database is sqlserver

Comment: There are several methods to connect sqlserver. This example of Entity framework :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-sql-database-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp-and-insert-and-view-the-data-usi/. you can connect sqlsrver with ADO.net

Comment: Oh thank you mate. I'm gonna use this reference of yours to complete my work. Gonna get back if something went wrong